# DRF ImportError: cannot import name 'action' on v3.8.2

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Why am I getting this error? I'm running v 3.8.2 of DRF. I'm wondering if docker has anything to do with it. Maybe the interpreter is trying to use/find some other installation I have on my machine. Any suggestions/help would be great. Thanks

This line is failing

`from rest_framework.decorators import action`

I'm replacing the list_route method to action on this line

`@action(methods=['POST'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, ])`

I'm running a virtualenv created in pycharm and running pip freeze gives me:

`$ pip freeze
...
Django==1.10.8
django-extensions==2.1.0
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
djangorestframework==3.8.2
...`

`backend_1   | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fa4163708c8>
backend_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
backend_1   |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
backend_1   |     self.check(display_num_errors=True)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
backend_1   |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
backend_1   |     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
backend_1   |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
backend_1   |     return check_resolver(resolver)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
backend_1   |     for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
backend_1   |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
backend_1   |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
backend_1   |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
backend_1   |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
backend_1   |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
backend_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
backend_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
backend_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
backend_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
backend_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
backend_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
backend_1   |   File "/project_backend/project_backend/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
backend_1   |     from apps.app_name.views import XYZViewSet
backend_1   |   File "/project_backend/apps/app_name/views.py", line 4, in <module>
backend_1   |     from rest_framework.decorators import action
backend_1   | ImportError: cannot import name 'action'`

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment ?

Comment: Yes I am using a virtualenv

Comment: You said something about maybe docker has something with it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not sure, thought i would just mention that I was also using docker.

Comment: open a python interpreter in the virtual environment, `import rest_framework` and check if the output of `rest_framework.__version__` is 3.8.2 and then in your Django view, do the same import and print version of the module

Comment: delete everything in that file except for the import action line. sometimes you get weird import errors like this when you have a circular import.

Comment: Console shows
```
import rest_framework
rest_framework.__version__
'3.8.2'
```

Running it in the view shows `3.4.7`. Is the action decorator in 3.4.7, sounds like it's not. Also why would this be running two different versions. I think some how Docker is running a different version. Let me ssh into the docker container and run the python console.

Comment: Inside the containers python console I get
`>>> import rest_framework
>>> rest_framework.__version__
'3.4.7'`

Comment: My requirements file doesn't specify a rest_framework version so it should be installed the latest, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My virtual environment and docker container were not using the same django rest framework version. I had to ssh into my docker container via `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` and run `pip install djangorestframework --upgrade` this gave me the 3.8.2 version I was looking for.

Docker installed 3.4.7 because I used to have `djangorestframework<3.5` in the requirements file and the container was stored in that state. I could have deleted the container and rerun `docker-compose up` to recreate the container with the newer version of 3.8.2. I of course opted to just upgrade with pip instead.

Comment: Same error as OP crashed completely my program and drove me crazy for a day (no error messages, no stdout, code pasted from docs). turned out that I had DRF 3.7 in the docker container and DRF 3.8.2 locally (for code supoprt in the IDE). Updating the old version in the container fixed the issue. This answer should be accepted